# Wrong file transfer over java Socket

Tags: java, file, sockets, io, file-transfer

this afternoon I wrote this class whose aim is give a easy way to exchange send a file over TCP Socket.
The problem it that, despite the final file size is correct, the content in wrong: precisely the destination file is made of various copies of the first buffer sent over Socket.
My class is simple: it calculates Q and R based on buffer size and sends this number together original filename to the client. I used a byte array to send data over Socket.

```
package it.s4sytems.java;  
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  

public class FileOverObjectStream
{
    private File file;
    private int bufferSize = 4*1024*1024; //4MB default, comunque è stabilito dal sender

    private static class Info implements Serializable
    {
        public String fileName;
        public long q;
        public int r;
        public int bufferSize;
    }

    public FileOverObjectStream(File file)
    {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public FileOverObjectStream(File file, int bufferSize)
    {
        this(file);
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
    }

    public void sendFile(Socket socket) throws IOException
    {
        socket.getInputStream();
        sendFile( socket.getOutputStream() );
    }

    public void sendFile(OutputStream outStream)throws IOException
    {
        sendFile( new ObjectOutputStream(outStream) );
    }

    public void sendFile(ObjectOutputStream objOutStream) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(file) );
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        Info info = new Info();
            info.fileName = file.getName();
            info.bufferSize = bufferSize;
            info.q = file.length() / bufferSize;
            info.r = (int) file.length() % bufferSize;
        objOutStream.writeObject(info);

        for(long i=0; i<info.q; i++)
        {
            in.read(buffer);
            objOutStream.writeObject(buffer);
            objOutStream.flush();
        }
        in.read( buffer = new byte[info.r]);
        objOutStream.writeObject(buffer);

        objOutStream.flush();
        in.close();
    }

    public String receiveFile(Socket socket) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        socket.getOutputStream();
        return receiveFile( socket.getInputStream() );
    }

    public String receiveFile(InputStream inStream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        return receiveFile( new ObjectInputStream(inStream) );
    }

    public String receiveFile(ObjectInputStream objInStream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(file) );

        Info info = (Info) objInStream.readObject();
        for(long i=0; i<info.q+1; i++)
        {
            byte[] buffer = (byte[]) objInStream.readObject();
            out.write( buffer );
        }

        out.close();
        return info.fileName;
    }
}
```

I created two classes to make some try...

```
import it.s4sytems.java.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(18000);

        while(true)
        {
            Socket s = ss.accept();

            File file = new File("G:\\HCHCK_72_5.38.part04.rar");
            FileOverObjectStream sender = new FileOverObjectStream(file);
            sender.sendFile(s);
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and client...

```
import it.s4sytems.java.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 18000);

        String matricola = "616002424";

        File directory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + matricola);
        directory.mkdir();

        File file = File.createTempFile("7897_", null, directory);

        String originalName = new FileOverObjectStream(file).receiveFile(s);

        System.out.println(originalName);

        s.close();


        File file2 = new File(directory, originalName);
        System.out.println( file.renameTo( file2 ) );
        System.out.println( file.getAbsoluteFile());
        System.out.println( file2.getAbsoluteFile());
    }
}
```

Probably it's a stupid thing, but I can't see it, so I need your help, please.

Thank you

Comment: Ok, I understand the fact that not checking the result of BufferedInputStream.read() is wrong, but I can't understand why I should not use ObjectI/OStream to send objects... yes, I know I could use DataI/OStream, but I want to understand why I have to.  However, thank you for your answers.

Comment: You don't have to. However in practice it is more complicated, especially when handling the last buffer, and it is also less space-efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ObjectInput/OutputStream code is flawed in all the ways Alex noted. I wouldn't use it at all, I would just use raw I/O. The canonical way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more, but megabytes is pointless as the network will packetize anyway
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use that same code when both sending and receiving the file. If you want to send > 1 file per connection, you need to prefix all that by sending the file name and length, which you can do with `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()/writeLong()`, and `DataInputStream.readUTF()/readLong()` at the receiver, and modify the loop control to read exactly that many bytes:

```
long remaining = size; // the file size read from the network
while ((count = in.read(buffer, 0, remaining > buffer.length ? buffer.length : (int)remaining)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    remaining -= count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `ObjectOutputStream` is suitable in your use case. Unless I missed something. In general, try to use some good library for IO such as [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/). It has methods that would always do the right thing. Look at [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) for example.

---

Some errors to highlight (they would not happen with good library)

- `in.read(buffer)` is not guaranteed to read exact number of bytes. You must check its result and only write correct number.
- You write buffer object to ObjectOutputStream with `writeObject`. That writes serialized byte buffer not raw sequence of bytes.

Comment: Thank you...   I don't understand very well the second point: why passing serialized buffers of bytes isn't correct?

Comment: @StefanoS `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` is intended to write objects to the stream so they can later be read in form of objects. So if you want to write `byte[]` buffer at the very least you will have to write some extra information such as length in addition to raw bytes. Otherwise, when you read it you will not be able to recognize when next object begins. The code would also write something to tell that it is indeed `byte[]`. You should abandon this ObjectOutputStream altogether. It's not intended for your task.

Comment: @Alex Gitelman that's not correct. He is writing byte[] objects and reading byte[] objects. They will be read as the correct length in each case. Whether he is actually writing arrays of the correct length is another question. However @Stefanos I entirely agree with Alex that serialization is not the correct solution here. He should just be reading and writing bytes, other than the control information, and it can all be done with DataInput/OutputStream. See my answer.

Comment: @EJP My bad. The code indeed reads them as objects. But all other issues still remain.